# Memory Leaks in Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: memory

How to find the memory leaks on Samung Device S2 (on device). I am trying to analyze the performance improvement in Samsung Galaxy S2 device.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is by using a memory analyzer. A nice tutorial can be found [here](http://ttlnews.blogspot.com.es/2010/01/attacking-memory-problems-on-android.html).

You will need to export the output of the PS command and do analysis  with hprof.